# updating a JSONb field in a postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table world with a field v (jsonb) and workflow_id (int). I want to run the command:
UPDATE world SET v = {'a': 1} WHERE workflow_id = 84;
This gives me a syntax error - I've tried putting quotation marks around the json value in all of the different combinbations I can think of but nothing works. If I try "{'a':1}", it tells me that column "{'a':1}" does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to do it as described in postgres documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
UPDATE world SET v = '{"a": 1}::jsonb' WHERE workflow_id = 84;
```

cause you need to cast your text to `jsonb` datatype.

else you can also try

```
UPDATE world SET v = CAST('{"a": 1}' AS JSONB) WHERE workflow_id = 84;
```